# Resizing an Image without losing any quality

Tags: c#, image, image-scaling

How can I resize an image, with the image quality unaffected?

Comment: Can you give us more details?  How large are your images, and what size do you need them to be?

Comment: http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/

Comment: http://imageresizing.net/ - This library produces the highest-quality images you can get with .NET

Answer (score 223):

As [rcar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality#87763) says, you can't without losing some quality, the best you can do in c# is:

```
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
}
```

Comment: I might add that (if possible) the user should start with a Bitmap image that is, say, twice as large as it needs to be and then scale down. The resulting image should be pretty smooth.

Comment: +1 for scale down. never up, whilst you can scale up, even coding an unsharp mask will not get you a good result.

Comment: gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality is better code.  Currently, HighQuality and AntiAlias are the same thing, but maybe in the future Microsoft will invent something new.  HighQuality should always be an alias for the best.

Comment: Method 'System.Drawing.Image.Save(string filename, ImageFormat format)' saves JPGs with quality 75. The image was blurry and not acceptable by the client. What fixed the quality issue was to use Save(string filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) instead and specify a quality value closer to 100.

Comment: This leaves artifacts on the border of the image sometimes...

Comment: I had artifacts on the border on using this.  Any suggesstions?

Comment: Is there a method to make it like http://i.imgur.com/RSjRttp.png to resize with blur effect?

Comment: @Roar there is no built in method for doing something like, you can certainly do it with a bit of code, but that would be a whole new SO question.

Answer (score 32):

Unless you're doing vector graphics, there's no way to resize an image without potentially losing some image quality.

Comment: unless you're expanding it...

Comment: You can expand it without losing any information, but there are different types of filters you can use which give different results - zero-order hold, low-pass, etc.

Comment: Can confirm, I dramatically said "Enhance!" to my computer and it didn't work.

Answer (score 26):

```
private static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{
    int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
    int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

    float nPercent = 0;
    float nPercentW = 0;
    float nPercentH = 0;

    nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
    nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

    if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
        nPercent = nPercentH;
    else
        nPercent = nPercentW;

    int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
    int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
    g.Dispose();

    return (Image)b;
}
```

### from [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing)

Comment: This works, but returns identical quality to Kris Erickso's answer. Nice to see Size used though...

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you're looking to do is "Resize/Resample" your images. Here is a good site that gives instructions and provides a utility class(That I also happen to use):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imgresizoutperfgdiplus.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can't resize an image without losing some quality, simply because you are reducing the number of pixels.

Don't reduce the size client side, because browsers don't do a good job of resizing images.

What you can do is programatically change the size before you render it, or as a user uploads it.

Here is an article that explains one way to do this in c#:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx

Comment: "browsers don't do a good job of resizing images" - this might have been true in '08, but luckily we're miles ahead in this area now (to a great extent due to old IE versions slowly fading away).

Answer (score 3):

Unless you resize up, you cannot do this with raster graphics.

What you can do with good filtering and smoothing is to resize without losing any **noticable** quality.

You can also alter the DPI metadata of the image (assuming it has some) which will keep exactly the same pixel count, but will alter how image editors think of it in 'real-world' measurements.

And just to cover all bases, if you really meant just the file size of the image and not the actual image dimensions, I suggest you look at a lossless encoding of the image data. My suggestion for this would be to resave the image as a .png file (I tend to use paint as a free transcoder for images in windows. Load image in paint, save as in the new format)

Answer (score 2):

See if you like the [image resizing quality of this open source ASP.NET module.](http://nathanaeljones.com/products/asp-net-image-resizer/) There's a live demo, so you can mess around with it yourself. It yields results that are (to me) impossible to distinguish from Photoshop output. It also has similar file sizes - MS did a good job on their JPEG encoder.

Comment: Well, JPEG is a relatively straightforward format. There's not much you can do to beat reference implementations in terms of quality/filesize because at the end it's just DCT coefficients with generic compression.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find also add watermark codes in this class :

```
public class ImageProcessor
    {
        public Bitmap Resize(Bitmap image, int newWidth, int newHeight, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, Calculations(image.Width, image.Height, newWidth));

                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                {
                    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height));

                    var myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(70, 205, 205, 205));

                    double diagonal = Math.Sqrt(newImage.Width * newImage.Width + newImage.Height * newImage.Height);

                    Rectangle containerBox = new Rectangle();

                    containerBox.X = (int)(diagonal / 10);
                    float messageLength = (float)(diagonal / message.Length * 1);
                    containerBox.Y = -(int)(messageLength / 1.6);

                    Font stringFont = new Font("verdana", messageLength);

                    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();

                    float slope = (float)(Math.Atan2(newImage.Height, newImage.Width) * 180 / Math.PI);

                    gr.RotateTransform(slope);
                    gr.DrawString(message, stringFont, myBrush, containerBox, sf);
                    return newImage;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw exc;
            }
        }

        public int Calculations(decimal w1, decimal h1, int newWidth)
        {
            decimal height = 0;
            decimal ratio = 0;


            if (newWidth < w1)
            {
                ratio = w1 / newWidth;
                height = h1 / ratio;

                return height.To<int>();
            }

            if (w1 < newWidth)
            {
                ratio = newWidth / w1;
                height = h1 * ratio;
                return height.To<int>();
            }

            return height.To<int>();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something out there, context aware resizing, don't know if you will be able to use it, but it's worth looking at, that's for sure

A nice video demo (Enlarging appears towards the middle)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIFCV2spKtg

Here there could be some code.
http://www.semanticmetadata.net/2007/08/30/content-aware-image-resizing-gpl-implementation/

Was that overkill? Maybe there are some easy filters you can apply to an enlarged image to blur the pixels a bit, you could look into that.

Comment: I suspect it has nothing to do with the original question, but I do love this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Are you resizing larger, or smaller?   By a small % or by a larger factor like 2x, 3x?  What do you mean by quality for your application?   And what type of images - photographs, hard-edged line drawings, or what?   Writing your own low-level pixel grinding code or trying to do it as much as possible with existing libraries (.net or whatever)?

There is a large body of knowledge on this topic. The key concept is interpolation.

Browsing recommendations:
* http://www.all-in-one.ee/~dersch/interpolator/interpolator.html
* http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-interpolation.htm
* for C#: https://secure.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageprocessing4.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=3657&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=629945
* this is java-specific but might be educational - http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1038068.aspx) that provides a C# image resizing code sample. You could use one of the [GD library](http://www.libgd.org/Binders) binders to do resampling in C#.