# Issue in resizeing an image to thumbnail size

Tags: .net, system.drawing

i have  an image  where   i am  resizing the image into thumbnail  size
 it  works  fine   if  i am using an image  size[700(width)* 600(height)]  orignal  size
 lets  say i have  10 images  of theis  size

**but if i use an  image around size[1100*1200] orignal size**
 it  resize the image into thumbnail but  doesnot match the size  of the   other  thubnail image

when  show in  listview    control
  **all the images  which are  size in [700* 600] are  shown  in one  size**

image which is in size in [1100* 1200] are  shown  in one  size[slighty smaller than  other images]

**so when i am displaying the image in
 listview control    so this looks  out
all 10 images are  shown in  one  size
but one image   is shown in a smaller
size**

**and  some times  all the  images are  loaded  fine**

but  some  images are not shown  only few images  out  10 images  2 images sre not shown

```
System.Drawing.Image objImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Images\" + sImageFileName));
if (sImageFileName != null)
{
    if (iThumbSize == 1)
    {

        dHeight = objImage.Height;
        dWidth = objImage.Width;
        dNewHeight = 100;
        dNewWidth = 100;
        objImage = objImage.GetThumbnailImage((int)dNewWidth, (int)dNewHeight, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(callback), new IntPtr());
}
```

this i the code  what i am  using
 i am  setting the size  height and  width    to 100

any help  would be great
 thank you

Comment: So you have 2 issues, one is the consistency of aspect ratio and the other is some resized images are not displayed, yea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality

Comment: ya that is the  issue what u told

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is with your code, however, I would suggest using a Graphics object to draw the image instead of using Image object. 
 
Here's an example:

```
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight); using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)) {
    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView control (and ImageList too) is designed to work with uniform sized images. This can be weird, but this is the situation. So I let ListView work as it wants. I created SquareThumbnail from all of my images from the normal thumbnails:

```
private void Thumbnail_Square()
{
    Size size = new Size(Settings.Thumbnail.Size, Settings.Thumbnail.Size);
    this._squareThumbnail = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, this._thumbnail.PixelFormat);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this._squareThumbnail);
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Purple, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
    size = this._thumbnail.Size;
    Point location = new Point(
        (Settings.Thumbnail.Size - size.Width) / 2,
        (Settings.Thumbnail.Size - size.Height) / 2);
    g.DrawImage(this._thumbnail,
    new Rectangle(location.X, location.Y, size.Width, size.Height),
    new Rectangle(0, 0, this._thumbnail.Width, this._thumbnail.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    g.Dispose();
}
```

I used `ImageList.TransparentColor = Color.Purple` in the form to make it look good.