# Resizing Images with ASP.NET and saving to Database

Tags: asp.net, image, image-processing, bitmap

I need to take an uploaded image, resize it, and save it to the database.  Simple enough, except I don't have access to save any temp files to the server.  I'm taking the image, resizing it as a Bitmap, and need to save it to a database field as the original image type (JPG for example).  How can I get the FileBytes() like this, so I can save it to the database?

Before I was using ImageUpload.FileBytes() but now that I'm resizing I'm dealing with Images and Bitmaps instead of FileUploads and can't seem find anything that will give me the bytes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Resizing an Image without losing any quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality) You can then write your image (Bitmap.SaveToStream) to a MemoryStream and call ToArray to get the bytes.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually not so simple... there are [28 non-obvious pitfalls you should watch out for when doing image resizing](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/). It's best to use my [free, open-source library to handle all the encoding issues and avoid the GDI bugs.](http://imageresizing.net)

Here's how to get an encoded byte[] array for each uploaded file, after resizing, cropping, and converting to Jpeg format.

```
using ImageResizer;
using ImageResizer.Encoding;


//Loop through each uploaded file
foreach (string fileKey in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Keys) {
    HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileKey];

    //You can specify any of 30 commands.. See http://imageresizing.net
    ResizeSettings resizeCropSettings = 
        new ResizeSettings("width=200&height=200&format=jpg&crop=auto");

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        //Resize the image
        ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, ms, resizeCropSettings);

        //Upload the byte array to SQL: ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

It's also a bad idea to use MS SQL for storing images. See my [podcast with Scott Hanselman](http://hanselminutes.com/313/deep-inside-image-resizing-and-scaling-with-aspnet-and-iis-with-imageresizingnet-author-na) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done to resize images.

```
    private byte[] toBytes(Image image)
    {            
        Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(image, yourWidth, yourHeight);            
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();            
        resized.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        resized.Dispose();
        return ms.ToArray();            
    }
```