# terrible image quality after resize

Tags: c#, image-resizing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resizing an Image without losing any quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality)

I'm resizing images using the following method:

```
public static Bitmap Resize(Image source, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

The output image quality is terrible bad. Is there a way to resize the image without messing up the quality?

PS: the image source width and height is always bigger than the width and height parameters and the width and height ratio is being preserved.

Comment: Try disabling the anti aliasing

Comment: @BlackBear That would _probably_ make it worse. Doesn't hurt to try, though. It's going to depend upon the image, too.

Comment: Make sure your dest bitmap is 24bpp or 32bpp or you won't have the range of colours available to do a good job of rescaling it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on resize and *resolution* of the image. If you make image bigger it's natural to get a bad result, you can get the same bad result on making image smaller, without maintaining its proportion.

In general, if you want to have scallable nice looking image, hold on Vector Graphics. 
In other words use: [Metafile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile.aspx) or some `SVG` library for images.

Comment: the image source width and height is always bigger than the width and height parameters and the width and height ratio is being preserved.

Comment: @lolol: in this case, try to disable antialiasing, or follow suggessions in other "possibe dupplicated" question, marked like a comment.