# how to convert jpeg to byte array without losing its quality

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I'm doing here is I'm copying an image file from a terminal to my server using ftp. But when I check the picture in the server it suddenly becomes poor quality image.

I'm starting to think maybe it's because of my conversion from image to byte array. Can anyone help?

Here's my code..

```
Stream stream = FileUploadPic.FileContent;

System.Drawing.Image i = new Bitmap(stream);

var abort = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

var thumbnail = i.GetThumbnailImage(300, 300, abort, IntPtr.Zero);

byte[] bytes = imageToByteArray(thumbnail);

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(path);

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
Stream req_Stream = request.GetRequestStream();
req_Stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
req_Stream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

This is the `imageToByteArray` function:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn) { 
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif); 
    return ms.ToArray(); 
}
```

Comment: Unless your `imageToByteArray` is doing something weird, it's not because you converted to a `byte[]`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard-here is my code in the imageToByteArray

Comment: public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

Comment: I've edited it into your question - you should do that next time :)

Comment: And I think I found your problem - check my answer!

Comment: oh..sorry @Blorgbeard,I'm still a newbie with stack...I'll try it out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif` is your problem. GIF is a rather old format, and is limited to 256 colours.

If you want to avoid recompressing a Jpeg, I suggest you try `ImageFormat.Png`, which is a much more modern format, and still loss-less.

Comment: I didn't notice that...thank you so much for the answer...Godbless you more!:D

Answer (score 5):

The loss in quality comes from using `GetThumbnailImage`. It is only intended to be used in fairly specific scenarios, [described in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

[This answer describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality/87786#87786) how to have more fine-tuned control over the quality and characteristics of image output in c#.

Comment: thank you rex for your answer. I've tested that part of my code. I've tried saving the thumbnail image to the same terminal and the image is perfectly fine. But whenever I upload it to the server. the image becomes somehow pixelated.