# C# change watermark image size depending upon original image

Tags: c#, image, watermark

I'm watermarking my images before uploading.
the problem im facing is if the image is small, the watermark looks to big..
i want to change watermark image size according to the original image..

for e.g. : watermark image should be 30% of the original image.
I'm doing this in c#:

> imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x,y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width + 1, watermarkImage.Height)));

What am i supposed to do to first get image size and then change watermark image size accordingly ??

Comment: Well... How are you applying the watermark? The `Image` object family have `.Width` and `.Height` values - so you need to do a simple scaling operation which preserves aspect ration and use that when you watermark but without code we won't be able to help

Comment: @Basic for watermarking :

imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width + 1, watermarkImage.Height)));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well then...something like:

```
Bitmap yourImage = ...;
Bitmap yourWatermark = ...;

int newWaterWidth = (int)((float)yourImage.Width * .3);
int newWaterHeight = (int)((float)yourImage.Height* .3);


using(Bitmap resizedWaterm = new Bitmap(newWaterWidth, newWaterHeight))
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)resizedWaterm))
{
  g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
  g.DrawImage(yourWatermark, 0, 0, newWaterWidth , newWaterHeight );
}

int x = ..., y = ...;
using(Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage((Image)resizedWaterm))
{
  g2.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width + 1, watermarkImage.Height)));
}
```

(Not tested, you also need to fill in values at the ... dots)

Code for resizing from: [Resizing an Image without losing any quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality)

Hope this helps!

Comment: can u tell me wat "destWidth, destHeight" are??

Comment: oh tats wat i was thinking... :)
n "x,y" is the location wer i want to place my watermark. right?

Comment: Xactly, they are meant to have the same values as in your original statement.

Comment: okays... :)
thanks..
and InterpolationMode gives an error.. i included system.drawing

Comment: hey thanks.. its worked perfectly..
i commented "g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;" @mortb

Answer (score 0):

NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();

```
            string pathToVideoFile = "D:\\Projects\\Project\\Db_Script\\TAR_Dummy\\TAR_Dummy\\Videos\\"+postedFile.FileName;
            string imagePath = "D:\\Watermarks\\30.png";
            string Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            //Convert videos from one format to another
            ffMpeg.ConvertMedia(pathToVideoFile, "D:\\Watermarks\\"+Id+".flv", Format.flv);

            //Add Aatermark to videos
            ffMpeg.Invoke("-i "+pathToVideoFile+ " -i "+ imagePath + " -filter_complex \"overlay=10:10\" D:\\Watermarks\\Images\\" + Id+".mp4");

            //Get video thumbnail
            ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(pathToVideoFile, "D:\\Watermarks\\Images\\" + Id.Substring(Id.Length-5)+".jpg");
```