# Inserting A mdi file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert a mdi file in a SQL Server 2008 table.

Do you know how can I do this?

My table has the following structure

```
Create table employées 
(
     Id_employee int,
     Mdi_employee image
)
```

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your MDI file into Byte format and then use normal query to insert that image.

For More information : [C# Resize jpg image, convert to byte and save into database using varbinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333488/c-sharp-resize-jpg-image-convert-to-byte-and-save-into-database-using-varbinary)