# Inserting picture from picturebox into database

Tags: c#, database

```
namespace dota2
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    private SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    private SqlDataReader dr;
    private SqlParameter picture;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::dota2.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        picture = new SqlParameter("@picture", SqlDbType.Image);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        open();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        savepicture();

    }
    private void savepicture()
    {

        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();
            ms.Close();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", a);
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into pictures (name,picture) values ('" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "',@picture)";
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Image Saved", "Programming At Kstark");
        }
    }
    private void open()
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
            f.InitialDirectory = "C:/Picture/";
            f.Filter = "All Files|*.*|JPEGs|*.jpg|Bitmaps|*.bmp|GIFs|*.gif";
            f.FilterIndex = 0;
            if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(f.FileName);
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                textBox1.Text = f.SafeFileName.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
  }
}
```

My form has a picturebox and `Open` and `Save` buttons. I'm trying to insert the picture from my picturebox into database using the code below. Picture opens as it should and shows up in the picturebox, but pressing the save button isn't working. It says either cn. Open is an error or the executenonquery.

Comment: Please post the exact error message, also please note you're using classes that implement `IDisposable`, that means you should prefer to put those items in a `using` statement. (eg: `using (var ms = new MemoryStream){ // do stuff with ms; }

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Resize jpg image, convert to byte and save into database using varbinary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333488/c-sharp-resize-jpg-image-convert-to-byte-and-save-into-database-using-varbinary)

Comment: The error is cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: That is not the exception, that is probably where it throws....

Comment: Can you post the exception message?  What you gave is the line that the exception happens on.

Comment: How exactly does the duplicate link posted **days ago** not help?  It shows precisely how to save to a DB **plus** how to optionally encode and resize the image!  it is a great answer.