# How to reduce the file size of the image but keeping the quality in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, image

Just wandering, how to reduce the file size of the image but keeping the quality in C# .net?

I have the following code use to save the image taken from ipad:

```
Bitmap srcBmp = new Bitmap(file.InputStream);

int w = srcBmp.Width;
int h = srcBmp.Height;
if (srcBmp.Width > 2732 && srcBmp.Height > 2048)
{
    w = 2732;
    h = 2048;
}

SizeF newSize = new SizeF(w, h);
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(w, h);
var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);

HttpContext.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
    graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

    using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
    {
        wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
        graphics.DrawImage(srcBmp, destRect, 0, 0, w, h, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Create))
        {
            target.Save(fileStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

The Image been saved is always over 14MB. Anyway I can keep the image quality and reduce the file size below 2MB?

Comment: There are many posts related to the same thing like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality), and also [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/resizing-image-in-c-sharp-without-losing-quality1), so check them out.

Comment: I think you mean *reduce image size* instead of *reduce file size* as your code ;).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that much reduction without decresing the picture quality is possible. However you can remove the metadata from an image using the [Exif library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43665/ExifLibrary-for-NET) without reducing the picture quality

Or if you are good with reduction in picture quality you can use [GID](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx)