# How to adapt the size of an image column of a DataGridView in C# WinForm?

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, windows-forms-designer, stretch

I have a table in mysql and i wanna show this table in dataGridView in c# winform.

My table contains text value type and image blob type.

When i fill the datagrid it fills correctly and it shows the values and my image.

But in this form:

[image]

Code snippet:

```
try
{
    MySqlConnection table_conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=picg; user=root;password=Alora36318");
    string table_query = "SELECT * FROM personal_info";
    using (MySqlDataAdapter adpt = new MySqlDataAdapter(table_query, table_conn))
    {
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        adpt.Fill(dset);
        show_table.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        show_table.RowTemplate.Height = 120;

    }
    table_conn.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string create_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal_info (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, last_name TEXT, position TEXT, personal_id TEXT, part TEXT, personal_internal_id TEXT, photo_path MEDIUMBLOB)";
    MySqlConnection create_conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=picg; user=root;password=Alora36318");
    MySqlCommand create_command = new MySqlCommand(create_query, create_conn);
    MySqlDataReader create_reader;
    create_conn.Open();
    create_reader = create_command.ExecuteReader();
    create_conn.Close();

    MySqlConnection table_conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=picg; user=root;password=Alora36318");
    string table_query = "SELECT * FROM personal_info";
    using (MySqlDataAdapter adpt = new MySqlDataAdapter(table_query, table_conn))
    {
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        adpt.Fill(dset);
        show_table.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        show_table.RowTemplate.Height = 120;

    }
    table_conn.Close();
}
```

How can i stretch the image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resizing an Image without losing any quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality)

Comment: doesnt deferent. i just need to make it beuty.so i can resize the column and stretch the image to it but i dont know how or i can resize the image and put it in column.but prefer the first way (resize the column and stretch the image)

Comment: hey olivier thank you for your comment but no that doesnt help me. im getting my image from database not from file

Comment: @.Alora Once you got the image from the database, resize it using the CellFormatting event of the grid and the method in the duplicate. To resize the column, use the Grid header collection items.

Comment: The `DataGridViewImageColumn` has an `ImageLayout` property. [DataGridViewImageColumn Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn?view=net-5.0) …. “Stretch”, “Zoom”